# Update Table A which has unique records is referenced to table B which do not have unique records on join

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

As the title suggests, I am trying to update a hierarchy tableA for lower level .one column a1 which is from tableA from a column b1 in another tableB which has assignments of the lower level.
The rule is to assign tableB.rcdind  to tableA.asgnflg when tableA.aid=tableB=bid and filter 
tableA.lvl_nbr=7(which is lower level)

It throws error as

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row when i execute the below update query.

```
UPDATE tableA A
SET A.asgnflg=(SELECT B.rcdind FROM
(SELECT  A.aid ,C.rcd_ind FROM  tableA A,(SELECT DISTINCT B.bid,B.rcdind FROM tableA     A,tableB B WHERE A.aid=B.bid)C 
WHERE A.aid=C.bid
AND A.lvl_nbr=7
))
```

the count of aid in tableA is 443, where the distinct count of bid in tableB is 138.

can i have loop in subquery so that it checks the aid same as bid and updates the column A.asgnflg

Answer (score 1):

The question is which `rcdind` flag do you want when there are duplicates.

You have two easy options.  The first is to take an arbitrary value using `rownum = 1`:

```
UPDATE tableA A
SET A.asgnflg=(SELECT B.rcdind FROM
(SELECT  A.aid ,C.rcd_ind FROM  tableA A,(SELECT DISTINCT B.bid,B.rcdind FROM tableA     A,tableB B WHERE A.aid=B.bid)C 
WHERE A.aid=C.bid
AND A.lvl_nbr=7
)
where rownum = 1)
```

The second is to use an aggregation function:

```
UPDATE tableA A
SET A.asgnflg=(SELECT min(B.rcdind) FROM
(SELECT  A.aid ,C.rcd_ind FROM  tableA A,(SELECT DISTINCT B.bid,B.rcdind FROM tableA     A,tableB B WHERE A.aid=B.bid)C 
WHERE A.aid=C.bid
AND A.lvl_nbr=7
))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordan Thanks for your reply, I want to update the table which do not have duplicates but only the lvl_nbr =7 so i used the below query.

```
UPDATE tableA SET asgnflg = (CASE WHEN asgnflg IS NULL AND A.lvl_nbr=7 THEN (SELECT     C.rcd_ind FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.aid,lvl_nbr,decode(max(b.rcd_ind),'Y','Y','N')     crnt_rcd_ind     FROM tableA, TABLEB WHERE A.aid=B.bid(+) AND A.lvl_nbr(+)=7 GROUP BY         A.aid,hrchy_lvl_nbr) C WHERE A.AID=C.AID) ELSE asgnflg END ) WHERE A.lvlnbr=7
```

I was able to update 443 records from tableA which has the lvl_nbr=7